# How can I use True Type Fonts directly with LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex

everybody.  I'm writing a book and my publisher asked to me to write it with several True Type fonts.

I was researching about how to do it and I found that it is easier with XeLaTeX.  Then, I noticed that the fonts in the LaTeX tree have the **.pfb** extension.  After that I searched in internet and I found this ftp page

http://www.walkonramp.com/mg/pdf/fonts/

There are several True Type fonts in that ftp page with the **.pfb** extension.  My question is

**Can I install (download and move to) these .pfb font files in my computer and use them directly in LaTeX, compiling with (for example) PdfLaTeX?**

If it's possible, **how can I do it?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use `xelatex` or `LuaLaTeX`... Have a look at `fontspec`.

Comment: .pfb are not true type but type1 fonts. And no you can't use them directly. You will need tfm, fd, map-files too.